# Horizontal pager issue method not call again for circular( rotation) feature android?

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

i used one library for horizontal pager scrolling  in that one onswitchscreenlistener method i have used but the problem is when i used setcurrentscreen method from onswitchscreenlistener method the screen will give same pagenumber

if outside of this page i will use setcurrentscreen than it will work pefectly also provide setted numbers

Ex: now last screen is 5 and if condition true and setcurrentscreen method call now screen must be 7 but instead of this it display 5 number screen if i print on log

https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager/blob/master/src/com/github/ysamlan/horizontalpager/HorizontalPager.java

```
public HorizontalPager.OnScreenSwitchListener onScreenSwitchListener =
        new HorizontalPager.OnScreenSwitchListener() {


            @Override
            public void onScreenSwitched(int screen) {

                if(screen==5)
                {
                  mPager.setCurrentScreen(0,false); 
                }

            }
};
```

Comment: any one help me give me idea so i will trace this code i dont understand exactly

Comment: actually i want to use the circular rotation means last to first when user swipe last to first